# Directory URLs for SEO: can the base directory name change when used by itself?

Tags: seo, url, subdirectory

Does it make a difference for SEO if I make my URLs like this:

```
mydomain.com/companies (main category exploration section)
mydomain.com/company/nike
```

As opposed to

```
mydomain.com/company (main category exploration section)
mydomain.com/company/nike
```

Does this matter for SEO?

Answer (score 2):

There will be no difference for SEO to choose one or the other approach for your URLs.

However, I think it will be better to choose this schema because it seems logical to me:

```
mydomain.com/companies (main category explore section)
mydomain.com/companies/nike
```

Indeed, the category page refers to a list of companies and a detail page for Nike is just a presentation of one company belonging to all listed.

Moreover, with this approach, you can implement your website architecture without the URL problem of choosing a different one for each category page.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution of

```
 mydomain.com/companies (main category exploration section)
 mydomain.com/company/nike
```

should be fine for SEO.  If you like the way that the main cateroy URL reads with "companies", then go ahead and use that.

Users do occasionally try to navigate a directory structure.  To support them, I would put in the following 301 redirects:

```
/company -> /companies
/companies/nike -> /company/nike
```